# Need help in java for changing c# code to java

Tags: c#, android, android-studio

I try below code in c# and work correctly now I need to use this method in android if anyone could change this code to java for android application

```
char[] chArray = this.textBox1.Text.ToCharArray();
            int[] numArray = new int[chArray.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < chArray.Length; i++)
            {
                numArray[i] = (int)char.GetNumericValue(chArray[i]);
            }
```

I try this code but don't work

```
EditText tld=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.uname);
    char[] chArray = tld.getText().toString().toCharArray();
    int[] numArray = new int[chArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < chArray.length; i++)
    {
        numArray[i] = (int)Character.forDigit(chArray[i],100);
    }
```

all of my issues at this line

```
C#==>   numArray[i] = (int)char.GetNumericValue(chArray[i]);
java==>     numArray[i] = (int)Character.forDigit(chArray[i],100);
```

Comment: This is not fit I guess for this platform

Answer (score 1):

use `Character.getNumericValue(chArray[i])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] chArray = this.textBox1.Text.ToCharArray();
            int[] numArray = new int[chArray.Length];
            for (int i = 0; (i < chArray.Length); i++) 
            {

               numArray[i] = ((int)(char.GetNumericValue(chArray[i])));
            }
```

Comment: http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/ This is the online converter  to convert c# into java